# R help command doesn't show R help home page

Tags: r, rgui

I have embedded R into Qt application (DyLoad R.dll and set bunch of callbacks e.g  ReadConsole, WriteConsole etc). On CentOS7.4, when i execute help.start() it brings up web page, but thd web page is always waiting on server response. The status bar shows message 
 "Waiting for 127.0.0.1:22665/doc/html/index.html".

Pls note that this works fine on Windows.

Appreciate any suggestion